# BenchmarkDotNet SimpleJob attribute: how so specify RuntimeMoniker equivalent to net6.0-windows

Tags: wpf, benchmarking, benchmarkdotnet

I want to benchmark classes in a WPF Class Library that multi-targets both .NET 6.0 and .NET Framework 4.8. Here's project file:

WpfClassLibrary.cs:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net6.0-windows;net4.8</TargetFrameworks>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

The class I want to test, simple instantiates a `System.Windows.Documents.FlowDocument` object:

```cs
namespace WpfClassLibrary
{
    using System.Windows.Documents;

    public class WpfClass
    {
        public FlowDocument Document { get; } = new FlowDocument();
    }
}
```

Here's the project file for the benchmarking project:

BenchmarkingWpfClassLibrary.csproj:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworks>net6.0-windows;net4.8</TargetFrameworks>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="BenchmarkDotNet" Version="0.13.7" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\WpfClassLibrary\WpfClassLibrary.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And the benchmark itself:

Program.cs:

```cs
namespace Benchmarks
{
    using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
    using BenchmarkDotNet.Jobs;
    using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;
    using WpfClassLibrary;

    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var results = BenchmarkRunner.Run<WpfClassBenchmarks>();
        }
    }

    //[SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.Net48)]
    //[SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.Net60)]
    public class WpfClassBenchmarks
    {
        [Benchmark]
        public void WpfClass()
        {
            _ = new WpfClass();
        }
    }
}
```

If I run this as-is the benchmark builds and runs fine. However, if I comment out the two `SimpleJob` attributes, the .NET Framework 4.8 benchmark builds and runs fine, but the .NET 6.0 benchmark does not. I get the following error:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
   at WpfClassLibrary.WpfClass..ctor()
   at Benchmarks.WpfClassBenchmarks.WpfClass() in C:\Users\stevensd\source\BenchmarkingWpfClassLibrary\Benchmarks\Program.cs:line 23
   at BenchmarkDotNet.Autogenerated.Runnable_0.WorkloadActionNoUnroll(Int64 invokeCount) in C:\Users\stevensd\source\BenchmarkingWpfClassLibrary\Benchmarks\bin\Release\net6.0-windows\7eaf257f-9929-493b-9995-b7827893b4db\7eaf257f-9929-493b-9995-b7827893b4db.notcs:line 311
   at BenchmarkDotNet.Engines.Engine.RunIteration(IterationData data)
   at BenchmarkDotNet.Engines.EngineFactory.Jit(Engine engine, Int32 jitIndex, Int32 invokeCount, Int32 unrollFactor)
   at BenchmarkDotNet.Engines.EngineFactory.CreateReadyToRun(EngineParameters engineParameters)
   at BenchmarkDotNet.Autogenerated.Runnable_0.Run(IHost host, String benchmarkName) in C:\Users\stevensd\source\BenchmarkingWpfClassLibrary\Benchmarks\bin\Release\net6.0-windows\7eaf257f-9929-493b-9995-b7827893b4db\7eaf257f-9929-493b-9995-b7827893b4db.notcs:line 176
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Span`1& arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at BenchmarkDotNet.Autogenerated.UniqueProgramName.AfterAssemblyLoadingAttached(String[] args) in C:\Users\stevensd\source\BenchmarkingWpfClassLibrary\Benchmarks\bin\Release\net6.0-windows\7eaf257f-9929-493b-9995-b7827893b4db\7eaf257f-9929-493b-9995-b7827893b4db.notcs:line 57
```

I think what is happening is that when specifying no `SimpleJob` attribute, BenchmarkDotNet is building benchmark using the appropriate `net6.0-windows` moniker. However, when using the `SimpleJob` attribute with a moniker `RuntimeMoniker.Net60` it's being built with the incorrect `net6.0`.

How can I specify a simple job that uses the runtime moniker of `net60-windows` and not `net60`?

Source code: https://github.com/DanStevens/BenchmarkingWpfClassLibrary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While one can specify toolchain explicitly in the config, [as suggested by mm8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76922298/660896), if the process is ran as .NET 6.0, the default Job config will recognize and use the "net6.0-windows" moniker automatically. So the following also works:

```cs
var config = DefaultConfig.Instance
    .AddJob(Job.Default.WithId("net60"))
    .AddJob(Job.Default.WithRuntime(ClrRuntime.Net48).WithId("net48"));
var results = BenchmarkRunner.Run<WpfClassBenchmarks>(config);
```

[Thanks Adam Sitnik for this answer.](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet/discussions/2408#discussioncomment-6751682)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use an `IConfig` to do this programmatically, i.e. you cannot use the `SimpleJobAttribute` directly:

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var results = BenchmarkRunner.Run<WpfClassBenchmarks>(
            ManualConfig.Create(DefaultConfig.Instance)
                .AddJob(Job.Default.WithRuntime(ClrRuntime.Net48))
                .AddJob(Job.Default.WithToolchain(
                    CsProjCoreToolchain.From(
                        new NetCoreAppSettings(
                            targetFrameworkMoniker: "net6.0-windows",
                            runtimeFrameworkVersion: null,
                            name: "6.0")))));
    }
}

public class WpfClassBenchmarks
{
    [Benchmark]
    public void WpfClass()
    {
        _ = new WpfClass();
    }
}
```

Or use command-line arguments to specify the runtimes:

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BenchmarkSwitcher.FromAssembly(typeof(Program).Assembly)
            .Run(args);
    }
}
```

Command:

```
dotnet run --configuration Release --framework net4.8 --runtimes net6.0-windows net48 --filter *
```